# $push into deeply nested array mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, push

my userSchema is as follows...

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    movies: [
        {
            name: String,
            duration: Number,
            actors: [{ name: String, age: Number }]
        }
    ],
});
```

In my NodeJS app with express I am trying to update my actors array to have another actor with value stroking from req.body.

I thought that I could do something like this...

```
await User.updateOne(
     {
          _id: req.user.id
          movies._id: req.params.id
     },
     {
          $push: { 'movies.actors': req.body }
     }
)
```

I thought this would push an actor into the specified movie `req.params.id` but does nothing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in this way:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1,
  "movies._id": 1
},
{
  "$push": {
    "movies.$.actors": req.body
  }
})
```

Note the only diference is the use of `$`. But with positional operator you are saying mongo where push the new data.

As docs says:

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

So you can update the element `movies.actors` pushing new data without knowin the position of the element.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gfv2QJTPsTC)

Comment: So I just actually got it working after I noticed I was able to change something using `updateOne`. I was trying to do the same thing all morning using `findByIdAndUpdate` and didn't work. Does the positional operator not work the same way using `findByIdAndUpdate` and guess that I had missed the `$` when I changed it to `updateOne`.

Comment: Positional operator needs to know the array reference. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wo9WP0_4Hou) example where I've deleted `"movies._id": 1`. Now mongo doesn't know where `movies.$` is. So I can't assert 100% but I think you can't use `findByIdAndUpdate` because you have to tell mongo the array where look the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
await user.updateOne(
            {$and:[{_id: req.user.id},{movie.name: 'I am Legend'}]},
            {$set: { movies.actors:req.body}},
        );
```

Comment: I get an error saying cannot create field actors

Comment: If I do not have actors in my movies array which I do not when I first create my user. I only have a empty movies array than it seems I cannot update this field

Comment: @J.F got the answer.